# Reduce footprint of .NET compiled to Wasm

Tags: c#, .net, mono, webassembly

I am using Mono to compile C# to Wasm in order to use it in the browser. Running the following commands procuces a bunch of DLLs, a wasm file, and some JS files.

```
csc /target:library -out:regex101.dll \
    /noconfig /nostdlib \
    \
    /r:$WASM_SDK/wasm-bcl/wasm/mscorlib.dll \
    /r:$WASM_SDK/wasm-bcl/wasm/System.dll \
    /r:$WASM_SDK/wasm-bcl/wasm/Facades/netstandard.dll \
    /r:$WASM_SDK/framework/WebAssembly.Bindings.dll \
    \
    regex101.cs

mono $WASM_SDK/packager.exe \
    --copy=always --out=./publish \
    regex101.dll
```

If I include these resulting js-files in a web page, I can run the transpiled code in the browser just fine. However, the resulting size (about 23 dlls + JS + Wasm) is around 15mb in total, which is very big, and I believe this is because there is no dead code elimination being ran, and large chunks of the framework is being includes.

I've been recommended to run a linker (see https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/issues/156#issuecomment-497281517) to perform dead code elimination, but being the .NET novice that I am, I don't know how to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Most people use a C# project (Blazor based for example) to build their applications, and then via a NuGet package reference to that IL linker they can easily achieve tree shaking. You should seriously consider that instead of compiling using csc. If you don't plan to, then you have to extract the things out of that linker NuGet package and use them (which comes with no documentation).

Comment: @LexLi Do you mean I should build my code using this blazor project? Could you help me set that up, or do you have any link to a resource that can clarify it for me?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: 23 dlls for 15Mb is quite standard in modern .NET, whether you like it or not :-) For example Microsoft's own "Try.NET" site is using blazor as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/hello-world?tutorial-step=5 and exhibits quite the same behavior (if you run it under a browser debugger, you'll see all dlls being loaded). Most "linker" stuff is today either experimental and/or just don't work for real world scenarios (and are hard to use because of the lack of documentation and good support)

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for the information. I hope you're incorrect, but if not, I'll have to find a way to deal with the large file size. Can they be compressed in any way?

Comment: The website handles the compression (if you look at "Try.NET" with Chrome, you'll see brotli is used for compression algorithm, for example mscorlib.dll goes down from 3M to 1.3M). And then the .dll are cached by the browser of course.